# I'm having trouble with jetbrains academy tasks

Tags: java

I'm supposed to do this.

> ### Multi-dimensional array  Cinema
>
> The cinema has n rows, each row consists of m seats (n and m do not
> exceed 20). The two-dimensional matrix stores the information on the
> sold tickets, number 1 means that the ticket for this place is already
> sold, the number 0 means that the place is available. You want to buy
> k tickets to the neighboring seats in the same row. Find whether it
> can be done.
>
> #### Input data format
>
> On the input, the program gets the number of n rows and m seats. Then,
> there are n lines, each containing m numbers (0 or 1) separated by
> spaces. The last line contains a number k.
>
> #### Output data format
>
> The program should output the number of the row with k consecutive
> available seats. If there are several rows with k available seats,
> output the first row with these seats. If there is no such a row,
> output the number 0.

But I'm stuck at finding a proper if statement to find the same adjacent coordinates k number of times

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // put your code here
         Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
         
        int dim1=scanner.nextInt();
        int dim2=scanner.nextInt();
        int[][] twoDimArray=new int[dim1][dim2];
        
       //  for (int i = 0; i < twoDimArray.length; i++) {
         //   twoDimArray[i][i]=scanner.nextInt();
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(twoDimArray[i]));
      //      }
      
      for (int i=0;i<dim1;i++){
          
            for (int j=0;j<dim2;j++){
                int current=scanner.nextInt();
                
                twoDimArray[i][j]=current;
                
             
             
    }
      }
             
                
                
             /*   for (int k = 0; k< dim1; k++) 
                {
                    for (int l= 0; l< dim2;l++) 
                    {
                        System.out.print(twoDimArray[k][l] + " ");
                    }
                System.out.println("");
                }
                */
                int seatsToBuy=scanner.nextInt();
                
                for (int k = 0; k< dim1; k++) 
                {
                    for (int l= 0; l< dim2;l++) 
                    {
                    
                        if ((twoDimArray[k][l]==twoDimArray[k][l+1])&&l<dim2){
                            System.out.println(twoDimArray[k]);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                System.out.println("");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a bit. Can you try the below modified code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int dim1 = scanner.nextInt();
        int dim2 = scanner.nextInt();
        int[][] twoDimArray = new int[dim1][dim2];

        for (int i = 0; i < dim1; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < dim2; j++) {
                int current = scanner.nextInt();

                twoDimArray[i][j] = current;

            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dim1; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < dim2; j++) {
                System.out.print(twoDimArray[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }


        int seatsToBuy=scanner.nextInt();
        int minConsSeats = seatsToBuy - 1;

        int rowNum = 0;

        for (int k = 0; k< dim1; k++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int l= 0; l< dim2;l++) {

                if (twoDimArray[k][l] == 0 && count == minConsSeats) {
                    count ++;
                } else if (l+1 < dim2 && twoDimArray[k][l] == 0 && twoDimArray[k][l+1] == 0) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count >= seatsToBuy) {
                rowNum = k + 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Available row number: "  + rowNum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First I'd name variables with expressive names, not i, j, k, etc ..

So first gather inputs, I think you did that fine, I just renamed variables:

```
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Number of Rows: ");
    int nbRows = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Number of Cols: ");
    int nbCols = scanner.nextInt();
    int[][] seats = new int[nbRows][nbCols];

    for (int row = 0; row < nbRows; row++) {
        System.out.println("Row " + row);
        for (int col = 0; col < nbCols; col++) {
            System.out.print("Col " + col +": ");
            int availability = scanner.nextInt();
            seats[row][col] = availability;
        }
    }

    System.out.print("Number of Seats to buy: ");
    int seatsToBuy = scanner.nextInt();
```

Then it is always useful to have a little sanity check on what was input, so here is a little snippet to print out the seats for debugging

```
    for (int row = 0; row < nbRows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < nbCols; col++) {
            System.out.print(seats[row][col] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Then I would use the following algorithm:
starts a counter at the beginning of the row to keep track of the maximum number of adjacent seats (`maxAdjacentSeatsInRow`). Then go seat by seat, if it is available, then increment the counter. If it is not, reset the counter to zero.
If at any point the counter equals the required number of seats, then that row is the one you want to return:

```
    int availableRow = -1;
    for (int row = 0; row < nbRows; row++) {
        int maxAdjacentSeatsInRow = 0;
        for (int col = 0; col < nbCols; col++) {
            if(seats[row][col] == 0)
                maxAdjacentSeatsInRow++;
            else
                maxAdjacentSeatsInRow = 0;

            if (maxAdjacentSeatsInRow == seatsToBuy) {
                availableRow = row;
                break; // break out of the col loop
            }
        }
        if(availableRow >= 0) {
            break; // break out of the row loop if we found a row
        }

    }

    // print out result
    if(availableRow == -1) {
        System.out.println("No seats available");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Seats available at row: " + availableRow);
    }
```

Sample output:

```
Number of Rows: 3
Number of Cols: 4
Row 0
Col 0: 1
Col 1: 1
Col 2: 1
Col 3: 1
Row 1
Col 0: 1
Col 1: 0
Col 2: 0
Col 3: 1
Row 2
Col 0: 1
Col 1: 1
Col 2: 0
Col 3: 0
Number of Seats to buy: 2
1 1 1 1 
1 0 0 1 
1 1 0 0 
Seats available at row: 1
```

The row index in the answer is zero based.
Also don't hesitate to make methods it makes things easier to read. Here is a version of the same thing but with methods:

```
private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("Number of Rows: ");
    int nbRows = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Number of Cols: ");
    int nbCols = scanner.nextInt();

    int[][] seats = gatherSeatsInputs(nbRows, nbCols);

    System.out.print("Number of Seats to buy: ");
    int seatsToBuy = scanner.nextInt();

    printSeats(seats);

    int availableRow = findAvailableRow(seats, seatsToBuy);

    if(availableRow == -1) {
        System.out.println("No seats available");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Seats available at row: " + availableRow);
    }
}

private static int[][] gatherSeatsInputs(int nbRows, int nbCols) {
    int[][] seats = new int[nbRows][nbCols];

    for (int row = 0; row < nbRows; row++) {
        System.out.println("Row " + row);
        for (int col = 0; col < nbCols; col++) {
            System.out.print("Col " + col +": ");
            int current = scanner.nextInt();
            seats[row][col] = current;
        }
    }
    return seats;
}

private static int findAvailableRow(int[][] seats, int seatsToBuy) {
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < seats.length; rowIndex++) {
        if(rowHasEnoughSeats(seats[rowIndex], seatsToBuy)) {
            return rowIndex;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

private static boolean rowHasEnoughSeats(int[] row, int seatsToBuy) {
    int maxAdjacentSeatsInRow = 0;
    for (int seatAvailability : row) {
        if (seatAvailability == 0) {
            maxAdjacentSeatsInRow++;
            if (maxAdjacentSeatsInRow == seatsToBuy) {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            maxAdjacentSeatsInRow = 0;
        }

    }
    return false;
}

private static void printSeats(int[][] seats) {
    for (int[] row : seats) {
        for (int seat : row) {
            System.out.print(seat + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```